# How do I fill an <hr> divider in CSS with a color?

Tags: html, css

[webpage with hr divider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urj2T.png)

I have a webpage with an hr divider and tried adding a color to it in my CSS file however no modifications seem to be working. Can someone help.

Here is my CSS file code:

```
body {
background: linear-gradient(black,white);
text-align:center;
}
#main {
    width: 1000;
    height: 600px;
    background: linear-gradient(gold, white);
    margin: 25px auto;
    border: solid 4px #FFFFFF;



}
h1 {

    text-align: center;
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font-size: 40pt;
    color: black;



}
hr{

    height: 6px;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `background-color` to fill an HR.

```
hr {
    height: 6px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 0;
}
```

Update: Added the `border: 0;` thanks to Roko C. Buljan comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked!

Comment: If I remember well, also a `border: 0;` would be useful for all browsers

Comment: Alright thank you, but why is that?

Comment: +1 upvote on answer and +1 upvote on @RokoC.Buljan's comment - I found both of these to work in my case.  Trey_32: the `border: 0` removes default the 3D-like/raised appearance of the `<hr>`, and in doing so, making it a nice flat bar, to use as mini dividers, which seems all the rage in terms of styling 2018+ (BBC site and others)